# Was this question right to be closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009076/are-there-enhancements-planned-for-javascript-numbers was asked a few hours ago, and I posted a quick comment on it, but it's now been closed as off-topic and the OP isn't sure why.

I'm not sure why either (I know the general rules for off-topic questions but this looks OK as far as I can tell). So I'm wondering if anyone can explain why it is off-topic, or if the closers were wrong.

To make this a more general question: are questions about the planned content of future standards off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, that question is off-topic. It is not a practical programming problem the user is currently facing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well the more concrete question would be "how can I represent an integer with a range of [some big range here]?", but I've seen a lot of other questions asked which relate to more abstract concepts, compiler behaviours and standards (hence my confusion). So how does this relate to that?

Comment: Planned future enhancements are off-topic.  The only way anyone here would know is by looking at specifications, which the OP can do themselves.  They're also localized to a specific moment in time, as once they're implemented (or abandoned) the questions don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @BilltheLizard OK that's clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off topic was incorrect.  As noted in comment, questions should be about a specific problem the user faces, but I disagree off topic covers this.  Note the off topic description says nothing of this sort, and in common SO parlance "off topic" means "nothing to do with software development."  Not constructive more accurately covers cases where user doesn't actually have a problem.

Too localized would have been correct.  Excluding duplicates, which are important to close with a link to the right question, it's okay if the question is closed for the "wrong" reason provided it's clear why it should be closed at all - the meta link covers this nicely enough, so not worth worrying about.